# What is run_once in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have seen the run_once method in some code like

```
run_once do
  [:hello, :core, :gems, :plugins, :lib, :initializers, :routes, :app, :helpers].each do |f|
    require File.join_from_here('mack', 'boot', "#{f}.rb")
  end
end
```

I found it in Kernel, but not sure what it does... something to do with running once I guess...

Comment: Is this in the context of the Mack Framework? (http://api.mackframework.com/mack/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is the [Mack Facets](http://api.mackframework.com/mack-facets/) run_once method we're talking about, here is its source:

```
def run_once
  path = File.expand_path(caller.first)
  unless ($__already_run_block ||= []).include?(path)
    yield
    $__already_run_block << path
  end
  # puts "$__already_run_block: #{$__already_run_block.inspect}"
end
```

You would call the method with no arguments but passing a block. `run_once` takes the first entry from the call stack (`caller.first`) to determine the point in code from which it is being called. It will only yield to the block if `run_once` hasn't yet been called from this call point (tracked by keeping the list of call points in the global array `$__already_run_block`)

e.g. it could be used along these lines:

```
def initialise
  run_once do
    # any code here will only execute the first time initialise is called
    # and will be skipped on subsequent calls to initialise
  end
end
```